# SQLAlchemy: warning for WHERE IN condition

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Recently I was fixing some bug related to pagination. It happened because of reverse join and a target rows appeared because of it. Like this:

```py
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = sa.Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, index=True)
    email = Column(String, index=True, nullable=False, unique=True)



class UserPermission(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users_permissions"

    id = sa.Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, index=True)
    user_id = Column(
        UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey("users.id", ondelete="CASCADE"), nullable=False
    )
    permission = Column(String, nullable=False, index=True)

    __table_args__ = (UniqueConstraint("user_id", "permission"),)

# results = db.execute(
#     select(User).join(UserPermission).where(UserPermission.permission.in_(
#         ["can_access_first_thing", "can_access_second_thing"]
#     )
# ).unique().scalars().all()
```

Sometimes, a query that executes to fill `results` would contain more rows than existing `Users` because for each user there will be more than one `UserPermission`. That breaks any pagination that is based on `offset`/`limit` approach. My solution for this pagination problem was to query `users` table again after determining all required user ids:

```py
base_query = select(User).join(UserPermission).where(UserPermission.permission.in_(
    ["can_access_first_thing", "can_access_second_thing"]
).with_only_columns(User.id)
results = db.execute(select(User).where(User.id.in_(base_query.subquery())))
```

Now SQLAlchemy throws a warning for this line: `SAWarning: Coercing Subquery object into a select() for use in IN(); please pass a select() construct explicitly`. My question is how to properly rewrite existing query so it returns the same result without throwing this warning.

Answer (score 18):

So I feel really dumb right now. After returning to this issue and thoroughly rereading a warning a couple of times, I've come to realize that all it says that I don't need to convert my existing select statement into subquery.  Then, the fixed statements would look like this:

```py
base_query = select(User).join(UserPermission).where(UserPermission.permission.in_(
    ["can_access_first_thing", "can_access_second_thing"]
).with_only_columns(User.id)
results = db.execute(select(User).where(User.id.in_(base_query)))
```

It's almost the same as before, but qwithout converting `base_query` to a subquery.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you might shorten your query builder even further:
`base_query = select(User.id).join(UserPermission).where(UserPermission.permission.in_(
    ["can_access_first_thing", "can_access_second_thing"]
)`